# Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible - Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructuring

I'm not a typescript expert and I am stuck trying to figure out the following error:

> Argument of type '({ keys, fire }: { keys?: any; fire: any; }) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, value2: unknown, set: Set) => void'.
> Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ keys?: any; fire: any; }'.

The block of code is:

```
listeners.forEach(({ keys, fire }: {keys?: any; fire: any}) => {
  //some code
});
```

Listeners is a set like:

```
const listeners = new Set();
```

and I am pushing an object into it like so:

```
const create = (keys) => {
  //keys can be undefined
  const listener = {
    keys,
    fire: useState()[1],
  };
  listeners.add(listener)
}
```

If I remove the fire or the keys from the forEach I still get the same error and I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NVK0Zm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz what about this doesn't clearly demonstrate the issue. I could add a bunch of other things that is completely unrelated to the question but it would be irrelevant.

Comment: If I drop that code into an IDE, it says "`listeners` isn't a thing I know about" (as shown in the TS Playground link from my earlier comment).  So before I can try to demonstrate the issue, I need to give a definition to `listeners`.  I'm asking you to do that instead of me, since you will know what sort of code will generate the error you're seeing, because you have such code in front of you.  It does take some effort to provide a [mre] (please consider reviewing the info in that link), but it tends to lead to better outcomes.

Comment: we need to see what `listeners` looks like because it's not possible to repro your error

Comment: If `listeners` is a `Set` that holds only values of type `{keys?: any, fire: any}` then you might want to strongly type it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqvzkW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not please [edit] the example to demonstrate a failing use case. Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz ya that works thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TypeScript [typings for `Set`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cd0434aa768da69515eb184c7f333729e663825c/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L58-L65) define it as `Set<T>`, an interface with a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter corresponding to the elements of the set. If you invoke [the `Set()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) without providing any type information, the TypeScript compiler will try to *infer* this type parameter.

For example, if you construct a `Set` and initialize it with an array, the compiler will use the array elements to infer the type parameter:

```
const setOfStuff = new Set([{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b: 4 }]);
/* const setOfStuff: Set<{
    a: number;
    b: number;
}> */
```

But if you invoke the constructor with no arguments, the compiler has nothing from which to infer the type of the set elements, and so it falls back to a default of [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown):

```
const oops = new Set(); 
// const oops: Set<unknown>
```

The `unknown` type can accept any value whatsoever, so it's very easy to *supply* a value of type `unknown`.  But on the flip side, since an `unknown` value can be absolutely anything, it's very hard to *consume* such a value.  The compiler complains that you are treating the elements of your set as if they were of type `{ keys?: any; fire: any; }` when all it knows is that they are of type `unknown`.

---

There are times when `unknown` is a reasonable type to use, but in your case, you probably only intend for your set to hold values of type `{ keys?: any; fire: any; }` and nothing else.  If so, then you can explicitly specify the generic type parameter when constructing your set, and thus strongly type it:

```
const listeners = new Set<{ keys?: any; fire: any; }>();
/* const listeners: Set<{
    keys?: any;
    fire: any;
}> */
```

After this, you can call the `forEach()` method and the compiler will know that each element is of type `{ keys?: any; fire: any; }`, as desired:

```
listeners.forEach(({ keys, fire }) => {
  //some code
}); // no error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmUDyAzAylArilMC8MY8A7jGogBQDaA3jAIYBcMAjADQwBGzATDAL4c6TGAGYO3GABYBAXQCUAbgBQAegBUMUJFgJk6LDmbkoAHhrKYVhszCYAtp3gAnFda62HT18v4A+GHVVZWVtaBgQEAAHCHxCEjJKJRg1VS1wcMiY40RTTDAAazAQYjA-ELDYABsAS2h4ImdYgiJSE3MYAvgATwgAfmZ6MG7FGBQa53hB4dH-CiU1TUqYWvrGiByzC3cu3oGGGctrccnpkd8AoJDVqAaXCAA6FBBnAFF6YAALCgo6XYgOCd4AJ5PgAtsYKpVBAQPZgaAACbwXxKIA)